# How to get all Parents of a node in tree structure ? (Linq to Entity)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, tree

I have a tree structure table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nodes](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [bigint] NULL)
```

What is the efficient way to find the path of a node as a list of parent Ids with minimum connection?

My Tree won't have more that 200 nodes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've test following solution on 100,000 records with depth of 30 level.
I get all items of tree, then a method fetch paths recursively until. End condition was null parent id. It takes about 4-5 seconds. This duration is acceptable while tree table will store 400 record maximum.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a complex problem if you need to allow for any level of nesting.

One solution is "Nested Sets", which trades-off an increase in complexity for inserts, updates and deletes in order to make querying tree structures much simpler/more efficient.

See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4155/Improve-hierarchy-performance-using-nested-sets

If you were set up this way, the query for retrieving the data you require would just be something like

```
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Nodes]
WHERE [LeftExtent] < @CurrentNodeLeftExtent
AND [RightExtent] > @CurrentNodeRightExtent
ORDER BY [LeftExtent]
```

If that's a bit too much I have seen people store the path as an extra column in the table, as a comma separated list of IDs. Obviously again this would mean you'd have to take care to update these whenever you insert, update or delete nodes.

Comment: Isn't it about binary tree @James? My tree isn't binary, so left and right child isn't applicable. right?

Comment: Ah the names "left" and "right" are perhaps slightly confusing, but nested set theory applies to trees with any numbers of children, not just binary trees.